# Почему после ajax авторизации, браузер все равно хочет пароль от юзера?

Tags: jquery, ajax, auth

Я хочу авторизировать на сервере пользователя через js, аякс авторизация срабатывает отлично и выполняется редирект на нужную страницу, на которой я уже залогинен через аякс, но при этом браузер снова запрашивает логин и пароль. Как избежать этого? (выпилить авторизацию на сервере нельзя)

```
$('#btnlogin').click(function(){
    var username = $("input#userlogin").val();
    var password = $("input#userpassword").val();  

    $.ajax
    ({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/cloud/",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
      },

      success: function(){
        console.log('ok');
        setTimeout(function() { window.location = '/cloud/'; }, 2000);
      },

      error: function(){
        alert('wrong password');
      }
    });

});
```

Comment: на русском, пожалуйста

Comment: @BOPOH, готово!

Answer (score 1):

Обычно сервер поддерживает сессию с помощью cookie. Очевидно Ваш ajax не сохраняет сессионный cookie. В последующих запросах сервер не находит этот cookie и не распознаёт клиента, как прошедшего проверку логином и паролем.
Ajax должен извлечь cookie из ответа севера и передать его браузеру для дальнейшего использования.

Comment: Это работает для Basic_access_authentication? ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication ), какой тогда формат cookie должен быть при этом?

Comment: Это работает для любой auth... Бывают конечно и другие механизмы, но этот самый распространённый. Другие тоже основаны на передаче в браузер какого-то, скажем, секрета, который браузер передаёт обратно серверу в каждом запросе. Какой именно cookie зависит от сервера. Их может быть даже несколько. На серверах java используется например JSESSION, но и это может быть изменено в настроках сервера

Comment: Ещё может быть расчёт на то, что браузер в каждом запросе будет передавать имя и пароль. В общем ищите инфу по вашему серверу.

Comment: Есть мнение что cookie должны автоматически приниматься браузер и в случае ajax. Так что может быть дело в другом или у вас вообще cookie отключены

Comment: Спасибо Вам, осталось найти только какой формат должен быть у этой куки.

Comment: Используя инструменты разработчика, встроенные в браузер, или fiddler можно легко посмотреть что на само деле происходит, какой ответ выдаёт сервер.